# Performance test "works on my machine", but not on the build server. What's missing?

Tags: c#, windows, wcf, teamcity, wcf-security

I've set up an integration test that mimics the production usage of a WCF service.

The code runs impersonated under a test user account present in our active directory. The test user is a member of the administrators group on the build server (running TeamCity 5.1.3).

The WCF service is in this case hosted by a console app, and is started by the test like so:

```
private const string _uri = "net.tcp://127.0.0.1:8090/bpaic";
private const string _tns = "tstdaily";    

...

_wcfProcessHandle = Process.Start(new ProcessStartInfo {
        FileName = _serviceRunnerPath, 
        Arguments = "\"{0}\" \"{1}\"".FormatWith( _uri, _tns ),
        UseShellExecute =  false,
        Domain = Config.Domain,
        UserName = Config.UserName,
        Password = Config.UserPassword.ToSecureString()
});
```

A `File.Exists` call ensures that the executable defined by `_serviceRunnerPath` is present.

The error manifests itself in the build server log like so:

> Test(s) failed.
>   System.InvalidOperationException :
>   Cannot process request because the
>   process (4332) has exited.    at
>   System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessHandle(Int32
>   access, Boolean throwIfExited)    at
>   System.Diagnostics.Process.Kill()
>   at
>   BondPriceAndInterestCalculator.IntegrationTests.Performance.MimicFMSTest.KillWcfService()
>   in d:\TeamCity Agents\Server Agent
>   1\work\40cccfdaa4a1ba8\BondPriceAndInterestCalculator.IntegrationTests\Performance\MimicFMSTest.cs:line
>   74    at
>   BondPriceAndInterestCalculator.IntegrationTests.Performance.MimicFMSTest.Calculat1000PricesAnd1000OutstandingInterestsInParalell()
>   in d:\TeamCity Agents\Server Agent
>   1\work\40cccfdaa4a1ba8\BondPriceAndInterestCalculator.IntegrationTests\Performance\MimicFMSTest.cs:line
>   69
>   ------- Stdout: ------- Unhandled exception in remote appdomain:
>   System.ServiceModel.EndpointNotFoundException:
>   Could not connect to
>   net.tcp://127.0.0.1:8090/bpaic. The
>   connection attempt lasted for a time
>   span of 00:00:01.0673145. TCP error
>   code 10061: No connection could be
>   made because the target machine
>   actively refused it 127.0.0.1:8090. 
>   ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: No
>   connection could be made because the
>   target machine actively refused it
>   127.0.0.1:8090    at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoConnect(EndPoint
>   endPointSnapshot, SocketAddress
>   socketAddress)    at
>   System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Connect(EndPoint
>   remoteEP)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.SocketConnectionInitiator.Connect(Uri
>   uri, TimeSpan timeout)    --- End of
>   inner exception stack trace ---

I.e., the exception doesn't occur at the time of process start, but rather when trying to kill the service after the test run. No work has been logged by the service so I assume it never was able to service requests.

Everything works fine on my machine (heard that one before? ;-)), but the WCF service doesn't get started on the build server.

What's missing?

Comment: What's the error message or exception? Is the test user seeing the path specified by _serviceRunnerPath? Check it by trying to enumerate all files in that directory... Or maybe the port is already in use?

Comment: +1 on the comments by @Daniel. Also, is the wpf tag relevant? Should be wcf perhaps?

Comment: @Fredrik Mörk: Thank you for pointing that out (it's got nothing to do with WPF whatsoever). @Daniel Hilgarth: I'll provide more info.

Comment: The real problem is not the kill. It fails, because the process it wants to kill doesn't exist. But that process does not exist in the first place, because the connection could not be made to the service. Did you check whether or not the port is already in use, i.e. if the WCF service can start? Another problem could be a local firewall blocking the connection to that port.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried going to d:\TeamCity Agents\Server Agent 1\work\40cccfdaa4a1ba8 folder and running your tests from this location? 
You should be logged in with the same account which is used by build agent service.

Answer (score 0):

Have you published the service on the build server at port 8090? It's saying it can't find the endpoint when trying to connect.

Comment: Yes, I have. It "works on my machine", remember? If it was set up to use another port, that wouldn't have been the case.

Comment: Yes but your test is connecting to the loopback address so you need to have it deployed on your build server. It has nothing to do with it working on your machine.

Comment: Deployment (i.e. starting the service) is a part of the test setup.